# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer

Tags: python, string, typeerror

This code returns the following error message:

- with open (infile, mode='r', buffering=-1) as in_f, open (outfile, mode='w', buffering=-1) as out_f:
  TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

  ```
  # Opens each file to read/modify
  infile=open('110331_HS1A_1_rtTA.result','r')
  outfile=open('2.txt','w')

  import re

  with open (infile, mode='r', buffering=-1) as in_f, open (outfile, mode='w', buffering=-1) as out_f:
      f = (i for i in in_f if i.rstrip())
      for line in f:
          _, k = line.split('\t',1)
          x = re.findall(r'^1..100\t([+-])chr(\d+):(\d+)\.\.(\d+).+$',k)
          if not x:
              continue
          out_f.write(' '.join(x[0]) + '\n')
  ```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're trying to open each file twice! First you do:

```
infile=open('110331_HS1A_1_rtTA.result','r')
```

and then you pass `infile` (which is a file object) to the `open` function again:

```
with open (infile, mode='r', buffering=-1)
```

`open` is of course expecting its first argument to be a file name, not an opened file!

Open the file once only and you should be fine.

Comment: Can you please look at my post and see what I'm doing wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286907/typeerror-coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer-nonetype-found-seems-to

Answer (score 10):

For the less specific case (not just the code in the question - since this is one of the first results in Google for this generic error message. This error also occurs when running certain os command with None argument.

For example:

```
os.path.exists(arg)  
os.stat(arg)
```

Will raise this exception when arg is None.

Comment: Thanks for this.  That python error code is really misleading.

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to pass file objects as filenames. Try using

```
infile = '110331_HS1A_1_rtTA.result'
outfile = '2.txt'
```

at the top of your code.

(Not only does the doubled usage of `open()` cause that problem with trying to open the file again, it also means that `infile` and `outfile` are never closed during the course of execution, though they'll probably get closed once the program ends.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best way I found for Python 2:

```
def inplace_change(file,old,new):
        fin = open(file, "rt")
        data = fin.read()
        data = data.replace(old, new)
        fin.close()

        fin = open(file, "wt")
        fin.write(data)
        fin.close()
```

An example:

```
inplace_change('/var/www/html/info.txt','youtub','youtube')
```